# Error after migration from TYPO3 v9.5.27 to v10.4.21

Tags: typo3, guzzle, typo3-10.x

After an upgrade to TYPO3 v10.4.21 from TYPO3 v9.5.27 the backand works well but the frontend shows me the following error:

```
(1/1) GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException  
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to xxxx:xxx:4020:805::200a: Network is unreachable 
(see curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

Comment: you should give more information. this shortend error message just states: there is a call which fails. no information about which plugin it initiated (try to identify by selective disable of extensions or content) or where the connection should go. Whithout more infos no specific help is possible.

Comment: I put that info in the question and anonymized the IP (delete your comment). that is more info, but neither helpful for others. you need to identify which plugin/ extension is the reason for the error. then you might find which server should be contacted and why it is unreachable (missing authentification, wrong routing, firewall, DNS, ...)